# Why is my code slower using multiple threads in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

So I have a program that runs a bunch of different calculations then returns a result when all the calculations are done.

Originally my code was synchronous like the following:

```
public class MyApplication{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        doCalculation(1);
        doCalculation(2);
        doCalculation(3);
        doCalculation(4);
        doCalculation(5);
        doCalculation(6);
        doCalculation(7);
        doCalculation(8);

        /* Print result */
    }
}
```

I thought it would be more efficient to run these calculations in new threads so now I have something like,

```
public class MyApplication{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
        threads.add(doCalculation(1));
        threads.add(doCalculation(2));
        threads.add(doCalculation(3));
        threads.add(doCalculation(4));
        threads.add(doCalculation(5));
        threads.add(doCalculation(6));
        threads.add(doCalculation(7));
        threads.add(doCalculation(8));

        for(Thread t : threads){
            if(t.isAlive()){
                try{
                    t.join();
                } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("Error calculating fitness");
                }
            }
        }

        /* Print result */
    }
}
```

I'm sorry, I'm a complete beginner to threads. If I had to guess I'd assume I'm spawn off two many new threads (there is about 50 calculations in my application), but any advise would be really appreciated!

Comment: And I didn't knew before this before :O List of Threads. Interesting !

Comment: doCalculation() likely does not take long enough to offset the overhead of thread creation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For optimal parallelism the number of threads must not exceed the number of CPU cores available, everything beyond that just creates overhead from context switching. Also, threads are expensive to create so letting a thread die after completing just one calculation is a big waste. Instead you should rely on the excellent support for parallelism which comes with the Java library.

My advice would be to use the Java 8 Streams API and formulate your problem as a parallel stream, such as

```
IntStream.range(1, 9).map(this::doCalculation).parallel().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This would be executed on the common ForkJoinPool, which is by default sized according to the number of CPU cores.

I assume that the overall work you are parallelizing takes substantial time on a single core (at least several milliseconds) and that no I/O is involved because those are the very basic preconditions for parallelization to be worth it. If there is not enough work to do, the overhead of task handoff to threads and result collection will eat away any advantage of parallel processing. If you do any I/O, then blocking will occur, occupying a thread while the CPU sits idle.

Answer (score 5):

Each thread has an overhead to start and join. If the work the thread does is significant, the overhead is worth it; but if `doCalculation` is pretty quick, then the overhead will overwhelm it.

Generally speaking, threads don't make things go *faster* -- they just make more things go at once. This can be worth it if you have a good amount of work per thread, and if multiple threads can go at full-ish speed at the same time (which is where multiple CPU cores help).

If each `doCalculation` takes X time, and you have 8 of them (and thus 8T overhead, where T is the amount of overhead per thread), then the overall program will take longer if `8T > 8TX` -- that is, if the overhead of spinning up 8 threads is greater than the amount of work to do all 8 calculations sequentially.

Comment: In a proper approach the threads would not be spun for each individual calculation so the essential overhead is much less and comes from task handoff and result collection.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik That's true, but it looked from this example that the OP has actually created and started threads manually (though on closer reading, they never actually invoked `t.start()`!)

Comment: What you say may apply to OP's code, but the point is that his approach can be much improved, and the end goal is speedup through parallelism.